# What is wrong with this edit?

Tags: discussion, support, rejected-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10191735

I saw an answer that was formally correct as to what exact action to take, but lacked any explanation as to what is going on. OP got it, I myself didn't get it first, and I thought this answer was easily improved by providing some short background information and clearing it up a bit.

Frankly, I don't understand this, and the stated reason the all three rejectors choose is only making me more confused.

*"This edit was intended to address the author"*? *"Makes no sense as an edit"*? I've come to understand that people are fussy about editing answers, but I thought this was a straightforward case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I actually belong to one of the reviewers who rejected the edit, let me explain why I did so.

Let it be said that I know nothing about `knockout.js` but that doesn't mean I can't judge a suggested edit. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) on editing posts says, quote:

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

None of those actions require an expert on the particular framework / technology of the post in question. An edit targets the presentation of the post (grammar / links / typos), not its content (the exception being incorporating comments).

For now, I will forget about the emoticon in the answer and only consider its text. So the first sentence is:

> Remember that you need the Parans to get the property of TestDate

The way I see it, there is only problem in this sentence, which is probably a typo: "Parans" should have been "Parens", as a common abbreviation to parentheses. Consider your edit:

> Remember that the mapping is turning all properties, including the date, into observables, hence you need the parentheses to access the value of your TestDate.

Again, the way I see it, you completely changed what the author said: you are suddenly talking about *mappings* and *observables*. This may be a very valid statement but, there, you *need* an expert to judge. You changed the meaning of the sentence. Whether it is a valid change or not is not for suggested edit reviewers to decide.

That alone is reason enough to reject the edit because: *This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.*

But for completeness, consider the second sentence of the post:

> That was the only line I changed.

Again, it is not for suggested edit reviewers to decide if this is relevant or not. It *looks* relevant: this might be interesting information to the OP.

There is another action that I could have taken, which would have had the same result to you: "Reject and Edit". Personally, I would have only fixed the typos and removed the emoticon, because that is really the only thing looking wrong in the answer. I chose not to at the moment I was reviewing.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how you saw it, it's helps a bunch in understanding this.

Answer (score 4):

Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content, not to add your own original content.  You can comment if you feel an explanation is missing, or provide your own answer (potentially referencing an existing answer) if your contribution merits it.

I'd also argue that "That was the only line I changed." isn't noise, and removing it is harmful.  Knowing exactly what someone changes to fix a code snippet is helpful, as it avoids the need for the OP or other readers to compare all of the rest of the code only to see that its identical.

Comment: What what, edits are about improving the "presentation", and not the content?

Comment: @Alex Yes.  Unless the post is a Community Wiki post.

Comment: Oh, this is news to me. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Alex Yes, in the help center.

Comment: @Alex http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing: "To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place." Would it have been ok if I added this new information into a comment and then edited it into the answer?

Comment: @Oldskool, hey look at that, that single sentence seem to be differing from these two different sources.

Comment: @Alex Leave a comment, then wait for the answerer to incorporate the suggestion in themselves. The point is to respect the original author's work. As Servy mentioned, you can provide your own answer if author does not incorporate your comment.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Then there is "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Comment: @Alex That doesn't in any way indicate that it's appropriate for edits to make significant changes to the *content* of the answer, merely that your post may be edited.  The types of things that are allowed to be edited indicates that the change you proposed isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy How about "To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place."? That is clearly about adding new information. If I had added my contextual explanation as a comment, would it be ok for someone else to later edit it into the answer?

Comment: @Alex That's there for information the author has posted (or approved of) from comments.  Primarily this is for when clarifying questions are asked and answered by the OP as a comment, rather than an edit to the post.